# Trying to find server ip address for red5 on wamp server

Tags: javascript, php, wamp, red5, live-streaming

okay so basically I installed red5 in wamp and am using videowhisper to try to live stream online but i cannot seem to connect to the red5 server that is suppose to do the rtmp streaming. I have managed to deploy and start red5 server but it just keeps on saying connecting to server when i try to run videowhisper. The red5 is installed on the www folders in wamp.

```
$rtmp_server = "rtmp://your-server-ip/folder-name";
// rtmp://your-server-ip-or-domain/application
```

I have tried

```
$rtmp_server = "rtmp://localhost/videowhisper";
// rtmp://your-server-ip-or-domain/application

$rtmp_server = "rtmp://localhost:5080/videowhisper";
// rtmp://your-server-ip-or-domain/application

$rtmp_server = "rtmp://localhost:1935/videowhisper";
// rtmp://your-server-ip-or-domain/application
```

yes i also took out /videowhisper at the end but no luck.

In red configuration this is the info i have

```
# Socket policy
policy.host=0.0.0.0
policy.port=843

# HTTP
http.host=127.0.0.1
http.port=5080
https.port=8443

# RTMP
rtmp.host=127.0.0.1
rtmp.port=1935


# RTMPS
rtmps.host=0.0.0.0
rtmps.port=8443


# RTMPT
rtmpt.host=0.0.0.0
rtmpt.port=8088
```

Comment: "PhpHtmlDeveloperEXPERT" - :-D

Comment: okay that was uncalled for. Actually I'm trying to do live streaming which most people don't know how to do.

Comment: it obvious if I don't know it no one else knows it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rajdeeprath/red5-development-series/wiki/Zero-code-live-streaming-with-red5

See the above link.

Try to install red5 out of wamp server.

Your rtmp is your local IP, on the web your isp IP is your web connection.

Example: local IP `rtmp://192.168.1.100/oflaDemo` see local
your ISP IP `rtmp://254.355.12.233:1935/oflaDemo` see on the web

Deactivate firewall.

this is link for web example: rtmp://254.355.12.233:1935/oflaDemo